# How to collect information after "if" or "else" statements

Tags: java, if-statement

I am trying to collect information about months regarding how far apart they are in regards to dates.

I begin by letting the User input what month they want to use.

```
Scanner uMonth = new Scanner(System.in);

String tMonth = uMonth.next();
    if (tMonth.equals("January")){
        int eMonth = 1;
    }else if (tMonth.equals("February")){
        int eMonth = 2;
    }else if (tMonth.equals("March")){
        int eMonth = 3;
    }else if (tMonth.equals("April")){
        int eMonth = 4;
    }else if (tMonth.equals("May")){
        int eMonth = 5;
    }else if (tMonth.equals("June")){
        int eMonth = 6;
    }else if (tMonth.equals("July")){
        int eMonth = 7;
    }else if (tMonth.equals("August")){
        int eMonth = 8;
    }else if (tMonth.equals("September")){
        int eMonth = 9;
    }else if (tMonth.equals("October")){
        int eMonth = 10;
    }else if (tMonth.equals("November")){
        int eMonth = 11;
    }else if (tMonth.equals("December")){
        int eMonth = 12;
```

Then the same for a second date  except I use a new Scanner
and use tMonth2 and uMonth2 for the next variables.

My problem comes when I try to use the eMonth variable outside of the loop.

```
int finalMonths = int(eMonth - eMonth2);{
if (finalMonths < 0);
finalMonths = (eMonth2 - eMonth);
```

Is there something I'm missing?
Can I not use variables from inside a loop?
Is there some extra step I'm missing?

Thanks.

Comment: Share the complete code, I can't see any loop in this code.

Comment: If you have declared eMonth variable inside the loop, then it will not be visible to the outside of the loop. As @saurav mentioned please share the complete code

Comment: I just wanted to mention this in case you do something like this in the future. The latest version of java supports switch casing Strings.

Comment: each block within the if/else has its own scope - the variables you declare there aren't visible outside of that scope. Move the declaratoin of `eMonth` to the top (before the if/else), and change each of those assignments to just `eMonth = ...` (don't redeclare them each time).

Answer (score 5):

The variable is only valid in the block where it's declared. Therefore you have to move the variable to outer scope in order to access it from both the setup part and computation part:

```
int eMonth; // variable declaration in the outer scope
...
String tMonth = uMonth.next();
if (tMonth.equals("January")){
    eMonth = 1; // only assignment, not declaration
}
...
int finalMonths = int(eMonth - eMonth2);
...
```

Comment: Yes, I found out about declaring the variable just before I read this.

Comment: Unfortunately, my compiler is still telling me that I've failed to "initialize" them. but thanks!

Comment: @AngelEscobedo : You need to init it in all `if` **and** `else` blocks or initialize it in the declaration: `int eMonth = 0; // some default`.

Answer (score 0):

you must read the scope of variables from  http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~calvin/cs110/LOCAL_GLOBAL.html and try declaring the eMonth before you start your if statement like

```
int eMonth;
if........the rest of the code
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem I see on the code you have created is that the using of long if else is not so readable. As A clean code recommendation I would suggest using an Enum class instead.

Use the following code as an example:

```
enum MonthEnum {

JANUARY,FEBRUARY,MARCH,APRIL,MAY,JUNE,JULY,AUGUST,SEPTEMBER,OCTOBER,NOVEMBER,DECEMBER;

    static Integer getValue(MonthEnum monthEnum) {
        return monthEnum.ordinal()+1;
    }
}
```

In any place you wish to use the Enum values as **Integer**, you can use the following:

```
Integer eMonth = MonthEnum.getValue(MonthEnum.APRIL)
```

And in any place you wish to use the Enum values as **String**, you can use the following:

```
String eMonth = MonthEnum.getValue(MonthEnum.APRIL).toString()
```

Using the Enum will prevent errors as you had using your code cause the initialization of the variable is outside of the if else statements. And you can see the difference in the code size which is much more clean and clear.

Another good reason to use Enum class is that the variables are **static** so it is more efficient in terms of memory decisions.

For more details about [Java Enums](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/08/enum-in-java-example-tutorial.html).

Comment: I think that is answer the problem of the confusion over scope of variables when using the separation of the if else section with the main code than the confusion is solved. and all the variables are kept in one section.